# Hazelcast get always returns null, containsKey always return false

Tags: scala, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Got [started looking at Hazelcast](https://github.com/Sergey80/hazelcast-steps-to/blob/master/src/main/scala-2.10/test/Test3.scala) (3.4.4). Minimal configuration. Test:

```
 case class Ticket(id:Int, name:String)

val ticketCount = 20
      val tickets:List[Ticket] = for { n <- (0 until ticketCount).toList } yield Ticket(n, s"ticket$n")

val map: IMap[Long, Ticket] = hz1.getMap[Long,Ticket]("com.foo.testmap")

tickets foreach { t =>
    println(s"submitting $t")
    Thread.sleep(10)  // some delay to submit one ticket
    map.putIfAbsent(t.id, t)
}


Thread.sleep(2000) // two seconds to make sure all is set..


var value1 = map.get(19)             // null 

var value2 = map.containsKey(19) )   // false  

val value3 = map.getAsync(19).get()   // Ticket(19,ticket19)
```

**Why** `null`, why `false`, why only `map.getAsync(19).get()` works?

This, though:

```
  val iterator = map.entrySet().iterator()      // will print all values
  while(iterator.hasNext) {
    val next = iterator.next()
    println(next)
  }
```

Will print all entries.

Update:

in config:

```
<map name="com.foo.testmap">
  <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
</map>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works as expected when you change `var value1 = map.get(19)` to `var value1 = map.get(19l)`

You are using Long as keys when storing data into a map. However you are using Integer to get the data back. As you can see in the IMap [contract](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) the equality comparison uses binary (serialized) form of the key, not the key itself. Obviously a long is serialized into a different binary than integer.

The `getAsync()` works as unlike the `get()` method it does use generics and I assume Scala compiler converts the key into a Long behind the scene.

It's a combination of auto-boxing and Scala compiler sorcery creating a seemingly inconsistent behaviour. However when I'm thinking about it it's not really that unexpected. Behaviour of `j.u.Map` is exactly the same. Following test is failing as well:

```
@Test
public void surpriseNotReally() {
    Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    long key = 1;
    String expectedValue = "foo";
    map.put(key, expectedValue);

    String actualValue =  map.get(1);
    assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
}
```